# variable of Variable

Tags: shell, unix, echo, csh

I have to print a variable value which is art variable. 
eg. variables are

```
A = X
Z_X = Test
```

Set in shell using

```
setenv A X
setenv Z_X Test
```

I want to print $Z_X value using $A

I am trying but without any success.

```
echo ${Z_${A}}
echo ${Z_[$A]}
```

could anyone tell me where I am wrong.

regards

Comment: note: you cannot have spaces in a variable assignment.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath you can in a C-Shell script. OP, are you using C-Shell (or derivative) or Bourne Shell (or derivative). The answers will be different.

Answer (score 1):

> A = X
>   Z_X = Test

This seems wrong; in `csh`, you need to use the `set` keyword to assign variables; in addition, the convention is also to use lower case for "normal" variables, and UPPER CASE for environment variables:

```
set a = x
set z_x = Test
```

You can then use `eval` to get what you want:

```
% eval echo \$z_$a
Test

% set x = `eval echo \$z_$a`
% echo $s
Test
```

This *may* be dangerous if you don't trust the source of `$a`, since it may also do a `rm -rf /` or something similarly dangerous (but if you trust the source of `$a`, it's perfectly fine).

You can get a list of *all* variables with `set`:

```
% set | grep ^z_$a
z_x     Test

% set | grep ^z_$a | awk '{print $1}'
z_x
```

Which is the only *safe* way I can figure out to do what you want.

Answer (score -2):

Generally this is a bad idea, and you should rather rethink your approach.

- You can use *indirect  expansion*:

  ```
  name=Z_$A
  echo ${!name}
  ```

  From the manual:

  If  the  first character of parameter is an exclamation point (`!`), a level of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of the variable formed from the rest of  parameter  as  the  name of the variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself.  This is  known  as indirect  expansion.   The  exceptions  to  this  are  the  expansions  of  `${!prefix*}`  and
     `${!name[@]}` described below.  The exclamation point must immediately follow the  left  brace
     in order to introduce indirection.
- Or *indirect references*:

  ```
  name=Z_$A
  eval echo \$$name
  ```

  You can find more about [indirect references](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/ivr.html) in the guide.

Comment: This applies to Bash and probably not to C shell which the question is using.