# create variables inside unix script

Tags: linux, unix, environment-variables, csh

I am trying to create a variable in a script, based on another variable.

I just don't know what needs to be adjusted in my code, if it is possible.
I am simplifying my code for your understanding, so this is not the original code.

The code goes like that:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set list_names=(Albert Bela Corine David)
set Albert_house_number=1
set Bela_house_number=2
set Corine_house_number=3
set David_house_number=4

foreach name ($list_names)
  #following line does not work....
  set house_number=$($name\_house_number)
  echo $house_number
end
```

the desired output should be:

```
1
2
3
4
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: May be helpful to read this: [Is it possible to build variable names from other variables in bash?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3963494/1983854)

Comment: @fedorqui Those all look bash-, or at least POSIX-specific. `csh` is a completely different Beast (that deserves the capital "B").

Comment: Same question [also answered here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604063/variable-of-variable/27606472?s=12|5.2651)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, the `bash`ism `${!varname}` is not available to us in `csh`, so we'll have to go the old-fashioned route using backticks and `eval`. `csh`'s quoting rules are different from those of POSIX-conforming shells, so **all of this is `csh` specific**. Here we go:

```
set house_number = `eval echo \" \$${name}_house_number\"`
echo "$house_number"
```

`${name}` is expanded into the backticked command, so this becomes equivalent to, say,

```
set house_number = `eval echo \" \$Albert_house_number\"`
```

which then evaluates

```
echo " $Albert_house_number"
```

and because of the backticks, the output of that is then assigned to `house_number`.

The space before `\$$` is necessary in case the value of the expanded variable has special meaning to echo (such as `-n`). We could not simply use `echo "-n"` (it wouldn't print anything), but `echo " -n"` is fine.<sup>1</sup>

The extra space is stripped by `csh` when the backtick expression is expanded. This leads us to the remaining **caveat**: Spaces in variable values are going to be stripped; `csh`'s backticks do that. This means that if `Albert_house_number` were defined as

```
set Albert_house_number = "3   4"
```

`house_number` would end up with the value `3 4` (with only one space). I don't know a way to prevent this.

<sup>1</sup> Note that in this case, the `echo "$house_number"` line would have to be amended as well, or it would run `echo "-n"` and not print anything even though `house_number` has the correct value.

Comment: Thank you Wintermute, that is a perfect explanation and I learnt a lot!